# Spring Data MongoDB XML Configuration failed to Authenticate against Mongo-database

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Currently, I am facing a problem with Spring authentication with MongoDB. I have the following declaration in my Spring XML configuration file:

**Spring Boot Importing of Spring XML file:** 
I am importing the below "spring configuration XML" file in my "spring boot main class" as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/Myapp-AppContext.xml")
public class MySpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
.... //Some Code goes here
}
```

**Spring Configuration XML File:**

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017" credentials="admin:mypass@mydb">       
    <mongo:client-options description="Connection to DB"/>
</mongo:mongo-client>

<mongo:db-factory id="myConnection" mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="mydb"/>
<mongo:template id="myOps" db-factory-ref="myConnection"/>
<mongo:repositories
    base-package="com.test.app" mongo-template-ref="myOps" />
```

**While running it as a "Spring Boot Application", I am getting the following error:**

> **Exception:**
>
> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential[]' for property 'credentials'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mongodb.MongoCredential' for property 'credentials[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found**
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1658) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1614) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 118 common frames omitted

**Exception Reason:**

As per my understanding, I believe the **"Spring-data-Mongodb"** JAR is missing a **"Converter" implementation** that converts the **"credentials"** attribute(It's a String type) to a **"com.mongodb.MongoCredential" array**.

Please let me know whether there is another enterprise version of the "spring-data-mongodb" which does support the authentication mechanism Or any other way of resolving this issue are welcome.

My Application uses the following versions of the software:

- Spring Boot version Used: 2.0.2.RELEASE
- Spring version Used: 5.0.6.RELEASE
- Spring data MongoDB Version: 2.0.9.RELEASE
- Mongo Driver version: 3.8.0
- Mongo Java Driver version: 3.8.0
- Mongo Driver Core version: 3.8.0 (Used alternatively with Mongo Java Driver JAR, as they are same)
- Mongo Community Server version: 3.6.5

Comment: please paste the code that how you import the spring xml file

Comment: I updated my "question section", on how I am importing the "spring xml" file to my "spring boot main class". I am packaging this application as an WAR and deploying it to Tomcat. Therefore my spring boot class is extending the "SpringBootServletInitializer" class.

Comment: can you paste the code of MySpringBootApplication?

Comment: Can you share a project to run that shows the issue. SD-MongoDB has a dedicated `MongoCredentialPropertyEditor` that takes care of converting the credentials string.

Answer (score 2):

I made it working in a different way. Here, is the final Spring XML file configuration looks like:

```
<bean id="myMongoServers" class="java.util.ArrayList">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <ref bean="myMongoServer" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="myMongoServer" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="localhost" />
        <constructor-arg type="int" name="port" value="27017" />
</bean>

<bean id="myMongoCredentials" class="java.util.ArrayList">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <ref bean="myMongoCredential" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="myMongoCredential" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
        <constructor-arg name="mechanism" value = "#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="admin" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="mydb" />
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="mypass"/>
</bean>

<!-- MongoClient -->
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="myMongoServers" />
        <constructor-arg ref="myMongoCredentials"  />
</bean>

<mongo:db-factory id="myConnection" mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="mydb"/>

<mongo:template id="myOps" db-factory-ref="myConnection"/>

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.test.app" mongo-template-ref="myOps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to changes in the way credentials were passed to mongo-driver.
With this, you need to supply ServerAddress and Credentials (part of which is password which is taken as Character[]).

SCRAM-SHA-1 is the mechanism used for authenticating to MongoDB. If you want, there are other method for different authentication with similar parameters.

If you are using Java based config, you can refer this snippet:

```
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort);
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(mongoUser, mongoDB, mongoPass.toCharArray());

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, mongoCredential,
                new MongoClientOptions.Builder().build());
        MongoDbFactory dbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDB);
        return dbFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Autowired MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
    }
```

Refer this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring xml configuraton

```
<bean   id="mongoServer1" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
    <constructor-arg    type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="190.6.5.167"/>
    <constructor-arg    type="int"  name="port" value="27017"/>
</bean>
<bean   id="mongoServer2" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
    <constructor-arg    type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="190.6.5.168"/>
    <constructor-arg    type="int"  name="port" value="27017"/>
</bean>
<bean   id="mongoServer3" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
    <constructor-arg    type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="190.6.5.169"/>
    <constructor-arg    type="int"  name="port" value="27017"/>
</bean>
<bean   id="mongoServers" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref    bean="mongoServer1"/>
            <ref    bean="mongoServer2"/>
            <ref    bean="mongoServer3"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredential" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential" factory-method="createCredential"> 
    <constructor-arg    type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="adminuser"/>
    <constructor-arg    type="java.lang.String" name="database" value="testdb"/>
    <constructor-arg    type="char[]"   name="password" value="adminpass"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoClientOptions" class="org.demo.helper.mongo.MongoClientOptionBuilderHelper"
    factory-method="createMongoClientOptions">
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="minConnectionsPerHost"    value="60"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier" value="10"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="connectTimeout"   value="60000"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="socketTimeout"    value="60000"/>
    <constructor-arg type="boolean" name="socketKeepAlive"  value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg    name="seeds"    ref="mongoServers"/>
    <constructor-arg    name="credential"   ref="mongoCredential"/>
    <constructor-arg    name="options"  ref="mongoClientOptions"/>
</bean>
```

Helper Class

```
package org.demo.helper.mongo;

import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;

public class MongoClientOptionBuilderHelper {

    private static MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = null;

    public static MongoClientOptions createMongoClientOptions(int minConnectionsPerHost,
            int tatbfcm, int connectTimeout, int socketTimeout,
            boolean socketKeepAlive) {
        if (mongoClientOptions == null) {
            synchronized (MongoClientOptionBuilderHapler.class) {
                if (mongoClientOptions == null) {
                    mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions
                    .builder()
                    .minConnectionsPerHost(minConnectionsPerHost)
                    .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(tatbfcm) 
                    .connectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                    .socketTimeout(socketTimeout)
                    //...
                    //...
                    //...
                    .socketKeepAlive(socketKeepAlive)
                    .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return mongoClientOptions;
    }

}
```

Mongo Java Driver Version

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Core Version

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```